# How to use modulescript to create a table of variables for a model's clones to each use?

Tags: lua, roblox

I already have a follow system. A model of a pet has been created and it follows the player around. What I want to do with this model is create separate variables for each cloned pet; so each player's pet has its own stats. To create a stats system with:
Health
Thirst
Hunger
Happiness
and be able to change and adapt these numbers for each circumstance.

I don't know how to go about creating this if anyone had any ideas it would be much appreciated!

I was thinking about using a table in a Module script so the variables are accessible in different scripts but this method I cannot figure out... Thanks! :D

The code:

```
 local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer 
local name = player.Name
 print(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can share you my method of storing avatars information.

You should create a `NumberValue` in a folder in the workspace every time a pet gets spawned. The name of the part should be the pet name or the player name, so you can easily find it.
To save more informations to the part you should add Attributes.

This way every script can easly access the values in `NumberValue`, And can always change them.

[image: Value]

Script to get the player name:

```lua
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local name = player.Name
```

Comment: Okay. I see where you are going with this. Would you be able to share your code that you wrote to get the player user name please? Just to make it easier than me asking a trillion questions. Thanks for getting back to me! Appreciated. :D

Comment: let me add the script in the answer

Comment: @Dr_ArmyDevRBX I added the script

Comment: Sorry its been a few days. That is what i was trying to do but didnt know which bits i needed as i was doing the service: players for whatever reason. Thanks so much fro sharing ill give this a go. :)

Comment: Its not letting me edit my comment above but anyway.  I think thats the code i was using but is giving me an error - ServerScriptService.LeaderstatsHandler:28: attempt to index nil with 'Name' - local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local name = player.Name
print(name)

Comment: @Dr_ArmyDevRBX add an answer with the script and tag me

Comment: Ive just edited it and put some code up. The script is in serverscriptservice if that makes any difference... It seems to have worked with this code though: ``` game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
 print(player.Name.. " Has joined the game!")
 
end) ``` @Karma idk

Comment: the function to get the local player can only be used in a local script. Another method to take then player can be the one you found, aka getting the PlayerAdded.

Comment: That makes sense. Is the function (playeradded) the only way on a serverside script to get player name?

Comment: yeah. there are other functions, but if you want it to start right away when the player gets in the game that's the only way

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much for helping me out. I have managed to get the name in my script!! :D